# Pandas DataFrame Column of Lists: Remove a Specific Value

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a column of lists. I want create a new column that is comprised of these same lists, minus one specific element:

```
[In]:
key1 = 'site channel fiscal_week'.split()
key2 = 'site dude fiscal_week'.split()
key3 = 'site eng fiscal_week'.split()

keys = pd.DataFrame({'key': [1,2,3],
                     'dims': [key1,key2,key3]})

keys

[Out]:
                         dims  key
[site, channel, fiscal_week]    1
[site, dude, fiscal_week]       2
[site, eng, fiscal_week]        3
```

Here is my approach that failed:

```
keys['reduced_dims'] = keys['dims'].remove('fiscal_week')
```

I need to be able to remove a specific element, not `pop()` off the last element.

Desired output:

```
[Out]:
                        dims  key  reduced_dims
[site, channel, fiscal_week]    1  [site, channel]
[site, dude, fiscal_week]       2  [site, dude]
[site, eng, fiscal_week]        3  [site, eng]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`keys['dims']` is a `pd.Series`, not `list`, and there's no `list.remove()` method. You should use [`pd.Series.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) method, which applies some function to the values in each row.

```
keys['reduced_dims'] = keys['dims'].apply(
    lambda row: [val for val in row if val != 'fiscal_week']
)

keys['reduced_dims']

Out:
0    [site, channel]
1       [site, dude]
2        [site, eng]
Name: reduced_dims, dtype: object
```

And you can't use just `list.remove()` function instead of list comprehension,

```
lambda row: [val for val in row if val != 'fiscal_week']
```

because `list.remove()` returns `None` and you will get such series:

```
keys['reduced_dims'] = keys['dims'].apply(lambda x: x.remove('fiscal_week'))
keys['reduced_dims']

Out:
0    None
1    None
2    None
Name: reduced_dims, dtype: object
```

Comment: What is interesting about the last because `remove` acts "inplace" if you don't re-assign back to keys['reduced_dims'], your column series is still mutated and this will achieve the desired results.

Comment: I hadn't thought of applying list comprehension, but it makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
def rem_fw(lst):
    lst.remove('fiscal_week')
    return lst

keys['reduced_dims'] = keys['dims'].apply(rem_fw)
```